# how do i make a request to the traccar API using Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have tried make the request, but I cannot do it.

This is my Retrofit interface that I am using.
With the session call, I am doing the Basic HTTP Authentication.

```
public interface APIService {

@POST("/users")
@FormUrlEncoded
Call<Users> saveUserPost(@Header("Authorization") String credentials,
                         @Field("admin") Boolean admin,
                         @Field("email") String email,
                         @Field("name") String name,
                         @Field("password") String password);

@POST("/session")
Call<List<Session>> openSession(@Body Session session);
```

}

And this is the onCreate method of my activity, in it, I am trying do the Login and verify if the user is registered.

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://http://192.168.1.72:8082/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    APIService apiService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
    Session session = new Session();
    session.setPassword("admin");
    session.setEmail("admin");

    Call<List<Session>> call = apiService.openSession(session);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Session>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Session>> call, Response<List<Session>> response) {
            switch (response.code()) {
                case 200:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error = 200", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 400:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error = 400", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 401:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error = 401", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 404:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error = 404", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                case 405:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error = 405", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+response.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Session>> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the native version of Traccar Manager for an example:

https://github.com/tananaev/traccar-manager-android/tree/native

It uses Retrofit. Here is the interface:

```java
public interface WebService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/api/session")
    Call<User> addSession(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password);

    @GET("/api/devices")
    Call<List<Device>> getDevices();

    @GET("/api/commandtypes")
    Call<List<CommandType>> getCommandTypes(@Query("deviceId") long deviceId);

    @POST("/api/commands")
    Call<Command> sendCommand(@Body Command command);

}
```